# Pandas Reindex Multiindex Dataframe Replicating Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Thank you for taking a look! I am having issues with a 4 level multiindex & attempting to make sure every possible value of the 4th index is represented.

Here is my dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(5)
size = 25
dict = {'Customer':np.random.choice( ['Bob'], size),
        'Grouping': np.random.choice( ['Corn','Wheat','Soy'], size),
        'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2018','12/12/2022', freq='D'), size),
        'Data': np.random.randint(20,100, size=(size))
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# create the Sub-Group column
df['Sub-Group'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Grouping'] == 'Corn', 'Sub-Group'] = np.random.choice(['White', 'Dry'], size=len(df[df['Grouping'] == 'Corn']))
df.loc[df['Grouping'] == 'Wheat', 'Sub-Group'] = np.random.choice(['SRW', 'HRW', 'SWW'], size=len(df[df['Grouping'] == 'Wheat']))
df.loc[df['Grouping'] == 'Soy', 'Sub-Group'] = np.random.choice(['Beans', 'Meal'], size=len(df[df['Grouping'] == 'Soy']))

df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year
```

With that, I'm looking to create a groupby like the following:

```
(df.groupby(['Customer','Grouping','Sub-Group',df['Date'].dt.month,'Year'])
    .agg(Units = ('Data','sum'))
    .unstack()
    )
```

[image: DataFrame]

This works as expected. I want to reindex this dataframe so that every single month (index 3) is represented & filled with 0s. The reason I want this is later on I'll be doing a cumulative sum of a groupby.

I have tried both the following reindex & nothing happens - many months are still missing.

```
rere = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-12-31', freq='M').month

(df.groupby(['Customer','Grouping','Sub-Group',df['Date'].dt.month,'Year'])
    .agg(Units = ('Data','sum'))
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0)
    .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(rere, level=3, fill_value=0))
    )
```

I've also tried the following:

```
(df.groupby(['Customer','Grouping','Sub-Group',df['Date'].dt.month,'Year'])
    .agg(Units = ('Data','sum'))
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0)
    .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(x.index.levels)))
    )
```

The issue with the last one is that the index is much too long - it's doing the cartesian product of Grouping & Sub-Group when really there are no combinations of 'Wheat' as a Grouping & 'Dry' as 'Sub-Group'.

I'm looking for a flexible way to reindex this dataframe to make sure a specific index level (3rd in this case) has every option.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def reindex_sub(g: pd.DataFrame):
    g = g.droplevel([0, 1, 2])
    result = g.reindex(range(1, 13))
    return result

tmp = (df.groupby(['Customer','Grouping','Sub-Group',df['Date'].dt.month,'Year'])
    .agg(Units = ('Data','sum'))
    .unstack()
    )
grouped = tmp.groupby(level=[0,1,2], group_keys=True)
out = grouped.apply(reindex_sub)
print(out)
```

Comment: This does work in this specific instance - thank you! To me, it lacks flexibility & is a hacky solution (through no fault of your own!). If it's not for an exercise like this, what purpose does the .reindex(xyz, level=3) exist? Is this a bug or a feature.